# Update a row if exists, if not create a new one MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting a name, number, and company into a DB.

My table is simply:

```
id(primary key)
name
slideView
company
```

I need to update this information if a name passed to it exists, if not create a new row with this data. I have looked at `REPLACE INTO` but I dont think that will work for me... as I dont touch the ID at all.

My code is:

```
insertData($name,$count,$company);

function insertData($name, $count, $company) {

    #Try/Catch statement to connect to DB, and insert data
    try {
        #DB username/password   
        $usernameDB = '****';
        $passwordDB = '****';

        #Create new PHP Database Object with the address, username, and password as parameters
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*****', $usernameDB, $passwordDB);

        #Set pdo attributes to handle errors 
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        #assign the sth variable (sth means statement handle) to insert the data
        $sth = $pdo->prepare("REPLACE INTO ***** SET name = ?, slideView = ?, company = ?");

        #Execute the insert
        $sth->execute(array($name,$count,$company));

    #Error if can't connect or insert
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }#/try
}
```

I'm new to SQL and havnt found a good way to do this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REPLACE INTO should work just fine - it also checks for columns with UNIQUE constraints.  So you would just need to [mark your `name` column as unique](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) so that REPLACE INTO will identify it as duplicate.

I haven't tried this particular use case, but the documentation seems to allow it.

Comment: I chose to go back to what I originally had. It worked once I marked my name column unique. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You might be better of using the `insert ... on duplicate update` syntax for this, although it will mean passing a few extra params but it can quash certain [problems in the replace into](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/18/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-replace-into/) syntax that seem to keep cropping up.

```
REPLACE INTO ***** SET name = ?, slideView = ?, company = ?
```

Could be written as:

```
insert into yourTableName (name, slideView, company)
    values (:name, :slideView, :company)
    on duplicate key update set
        slideView=:$slideView2, company=:company2
```

and then the execute is done like this:

```
$sth->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':slideView' => $count,
    ':company' => $company, ':slideView2' => $count, ':company2' => $company));
```

The format above uses named paramaters (they are ever so much easier to read/debug) and will insert a new row into the database - or if the unique/primary key column `name` already has the value, then update the row with the remainder of the information.

You do have to use paramaters twice here (even though slideView and company will contain the same information) as no parameter can be used twice in a query.

Comment: This seems correct. Although it is throwing this error:`Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET slideView=NULL, company=NULL' at line 1`

Comment: Also, I am running MySQL version `5.1.61`

Comment: I removed `SET` and the query ran, although it didn't update anything - just kept adding new rows each time.

Comment: @mdance You do have `name` in your table set as a unique row yes?